# i2c device not detected on beaglebone black (MS5803-14BA Pressure Sensor)

Tags: linux, node.js, beagleboneblack, i2c

I am unable to detect [MS5803-14BA Pressure Sensor](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ms5803-14ba-pressure-sensor-hookup-guide) through probing i2c devices using ic2 tools on Beaglebone Black.

The sensor works perfect on arduino uno using library provided by [sparkfun](https://github.com/sparkfun/MS5803-14BA_Breakout/archive/master.zip), so I ruled out that the sensor might be damaged.

I am connecting i2c sensors do the beaglebone black as follows:

vcc  P9_4,
GND  P9_2,
SCL  P9_19,
SDA  P9_20

on i2c-1 bus

Other sensors are getting detected (eg MPU6050), but for some reason MS5803-14BA sensor is not.

I doublechecked all connections are correct.

Do I need pull up resistors or a linux driver?

I am running Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone70 and I am willing to read this sensor in Node.js.

Please help before I go mad...

Kind regards